# how to display nested data in table laravel

Tags: laravel, html-table, nested

[image]

How can I get the result as drawn on the right

in Controller

`$programs = Program::with(['activities', 'activites.subactivities'])->get();`

in Blade View

```
@foreach ($programs as $programKey => $program)
    @foreach ($program->activities as $activity)
        @foreach ($activity->subactivities->toArray() as $subactivity)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $programKey + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ strtoupper($program->name) }}</td>
            <td>{{ $activity->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $subactivity['name'] }}</td>
        </tr>
   @endforeach
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: What's your result for `dd()` for `programs` in controller?

Comment: ```[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Program 1",
    "user_id": 1,
    "activities": [
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "xxxxxx",
        "program_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "subactivities": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "subactivity 1",
            "activity_id": 14,
            "user_id": 1
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "subactivity 2",
            "activity_id": 14,
            "user_id": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]```

Comment: have you tried using `order by` eloquent in your query to organize your object according to programs? I.e. `program 1 ` and `program 2` etc?

Comment: yes, but I get the same result

Comment: I'm confused how to set it on the blade according to the picture I sent above

Answer (score 0):

I would say to save in a variable and if different the show

Like this:

```
@foreach ($programs as $programKey => $program)
 @php
    $newProgram = true;
 @endphp
  @foreach ($program->activities as $activityKey => $activity)
    @php
        $newActivity = true;
    @endphp
    @foreach ($activity->subactivities->toArray() as $subactivity)
        <tr>
            <td>
                @if($newProgram == true)
                    {{ $programKey + 1 }}
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>
                @if($newProgram == true)
                    {{ strtoupper($program->name) }}
                    @php
                        $newProgram = false;
                    @endphp
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>
                @if($newActivity == true)
                    {{ $activity->name }}
                    @php
                        $newActivity = false;
                    @endphp
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ $subactivity['name'] }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```